# could not find generator acts_as_taggable_migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, acts-as-taggable-on-ster

in my rails3 app i installed acts_as_taggable_on_steroids through command "rails plugin install acts_as_taggable_on_steroids" and it got installed,but now the migration give me the problem.

I run "rails generate acts_as_taggable_migration",but the error comes "could not find generator acts_as_taggable_migration", please help

Answer (score 4):

manage to figure out a workaround in 3 steps:

1) `$ rails generate migration acts_as_taggable`

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20110710214842_acts_as_taggable.rb
```

2) Overwrite with migration info
**$ cat lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids-1.2/generators/acts_as_taggable_migration/templates/migration.rb  > 20110710223844_acts_as_taggable_migration.rb**

3) Migrate

```
$ rake db:migrate
(in c:/Sites/bon)
==  ActsAsTaggable: migrating =================================================
==  ActsAsTaggable: migrated (0.0000s) ========================================

==  ActsAsTaggableMigration: migrating ========================================
-- create_table(:tags)
   -> 0.0020s
-- create_table(:taggings)
   -> 0.0010s
-- add_index(:taggings, :tag_id)
   -> 0.0010s
-- add_index(:taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type])
   -> 0.0010s
==  ActsAsTaggableMigration: migrated (0.0140s) ===============================
```

validate with `$ rake db:migration:status`

Answer (score 2):

The install migration comment for the latest version of rails (3.0 +) has changed:

```
# For the latest versions :
rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
```

[Details on acts as taggable on Github project](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue which was the same as the question above.

```
rails generate migration acts_as_taggable
rake acts_as_taggable_on_engine:install:migrations
```

Link to github documentation https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on